# Get server name without using server variable in php(laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.2 and want to execute cron job in development environment. There is a scripts in bootstarp/start.php which have code to detect environment

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {
     return $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'hostname' ? 'dev' : 'production';
});
```

I have setup a cron job to perform task but it always detect production environment. It is because server variable is not available in CLI mode. please suggest alternative of server variable to get SERVER NAME.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel stores `env` on its Application's `env` magic property which you may call it by

```
App::make('env')
```

But it's better to use its available method

```
App::environment() // e.g. "production"
App::environment('production') // performs check, current env == "production"
App::environment('production', 'dev') // performs check, current env is either one listed
```

Comment: Ummm, heres a reference https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L231